variables empty when sent to API endpoint in Laravel
I'm trying to send a set of form inputs from a controller into an API endpoint but when I check the variables in the API, it all shows null value.. what is wrong with my code?
CulinaryController.php
    public function update(Request $request, Culinary $culinary)
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $token = Session('token');

        try {
            $multipart = [];

            foreach ($request->except('cover_photo') as $key => $value) {
                $multipart[] = [
                    'name' => $key,
                    'contents' => $value,
                ];
            }
            
            if ($request->hasFile('cover_photo')) {
                $coverPhoto = $request->file('cover_photo');
                $multipart[] = [
                    'name' => 'cover_photo',
                    'contents' => fopen($coverPhoto->getRealPath(), 'r'),
                    'filename' => $coverPhoto->getClientOriginalName(),
                ];
            }
            dd($multipart);
            
            $url = 'http://localhost/api/v1/culinary/'.$culinary->id;
            $response = $client->put($url, [
                'multipart' => $multipart,
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
                    'Accept' => 'application/json',
                ]
            ]);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['errors' => $e->getMessage()])->withInput();
        }
    }

api/v1/CulinaryController.php
    public function update(Request $request, Culinary $culinary)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'test',
            'request' => $request->all(),
            'foo' => request('title'),
            'file' => $request->file('cover_photo'),
            'culinary' => $culinary,
        ]);
    }

routes/api.php
    Route::apiResource('culinary', CulinaryController::class);

when I uncomment the dd($multipart) in the controller, it contains 7 sets of input below so I'm sure the form wasn't empty when submitted.
array:9 [▼ // app\Http\Controllers\AdminCulinaryController.php:198
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "_token"
    "contents" => "TwpS0e7OJH1jhhR1dr8RBpCiYKW4vhVyuk3CRZWC"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "_method"
    "contents" => "PUT"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "title"
    "contents" => "Et in quia ut et illo harum."
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "old_cover_photo"
    "contents" => "https://via.placeholder.com/640x480.png/0022bb?text=distinctio"
  ]
  4 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "country_id"
    "contents" => "188"
  ]
  5 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "category_name"
    "contents" => "vegetarian"
  ]
  6 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "prologue"
    "contents" => "Adipisci iure nihil sit voluptatem rerum voluptatibus. Qui aperiam et magnam corrupti quia eius reprehenderit. Sunt non aut dolores. Dolorem nesciunt atque ipsa
 ▶
"
  ]
  7 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "body"
    "contents" => "Autem iure qui magni excepturi hic. Laudantium adipisci saepe odio quod cupiditate. Blanditiis occaecati sint at sint incidunt optio illum nihil."
  ]
  8 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "opening_hours"
    "contents" => "Qui et magnam labore a ea corrupti."
  ]
]


What Client are you making your request with?

@OluwafemiSule I'm using guzzlehttp

I think your answer lies here. PHP supports multipart/form-data only for POST requests and not PUT.

The issue is fixed in PHP 8.4. You'll likely have to update your PHP version to resolve it.

if I'm not mistaken, PHP 8.4 isn't released yet, right?

You're right about that. It's set to be released on 2024-11-21. You may want to consider the workarounds in the SO question that I linked to or use rc images

Did you recreate the question? I added a comment on the previous question where you are passing $multipart variable (an array) from CulinaryController@update to APICulinaryController@update However you are accessing cover_photo directly. Check $request->all() in the APICulinaryController@update

looks like so. I'm just too dizzy right now that I can't think straight.. anyway, I tried @OluwafemiSule's advice and added enctype="multipart/form-data" to my form and it seems to do the trick

@Mr.Kenneth oh I think I see it now. my previous question was about the file upload not being sent to the api endpoint, but this one is about the entire $request->all() variable being empty in the api endpoint. I changed too many small things in the code that I lost track of what caused this.

$response = $client->put($url, [
    'multipart' => $multipart,
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data',
    ]
   ]);

May be update content-type and try

I studied your question . you can use a below package for a solution your problem :
composer require alireaza/php-form-data

In php we have multipart/form-data in POST method request but you have use PUT method.i have a suggest for you. please test $request->all() at the beginning of your function (update) and check type of 'cover-photo' parameter. if you recieve array type its ok but you should use a package for config multipart/form-data on your PUT Request.
good luck
